# XMPP receive history without rejoining the MUC

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

Suppose A has already joined into the MUC. At the time of join A will receive complete history. But after that is there any way for A to receive the complete history any number of times by doing some query to MUC.
Leaving and Rejoining the MUC is not acceptable. :(

I have seen [How to re-request room roster and history from a muc in ejabberd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255396/how-to-re-request-room-roster-and-history-from-a-muc-in-ejabberd)

But the last comment with  is not working for me.
Please help me, if this is even possible or not. If yes can you give me the stanza that needs to be sent to muc. BTW I am using smack API and openfire

Thanks,
Nitiraj

Comment: I can only ask... why? :) (because XMPP isn't lossy, if you got sent the history then you should still have it locally if you need it)

Comment: @samirprogrammer : No, I could not find any solution. I had to use the leave and rejoining MUC trick. :(